# fetch data from a collection by checking a condition in another collection

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am working on angular-meteor.
In my db there are two collections namely subscriptions and school.
Subscriptions:

```
[
{
    "_id" : "9qAcc86yhG7hSxejL",

    "school" : {
        "_id" : "uz7rMGXJwn566GhBg"
    },

 "wrk_status":"completed"


},
{
    "_id" : "9qAcc86yhG7hSxejL",

    "school" : {
        "_id" : "uz7oMGXJwn566GhBg"
    },

 "wrk_status":"pending"


},
{
    "_id" : "9qAcc86yhG7hSxejL",

    "school" : {
        "_id" : "uz7pMGXJwn566GhBg"
    },

 "wrk_status":"completed"


}]
```

School:

```
[
{
    "_id" : "uz7rMGXJwn566GhBg",

    "name" : "The Oxford School",
    "address" : "Trivandrum",

    "status" : "new",

    },
{
    "_id" : "uz7oMGXJwn566GhBg",

    "name" : "The  School",
    "address" : "Trivandrum",

    "status" : "new",

    },
{
    "_id" : "uz7pMGXJwn566GhBg",

    "name" : "The new School",
    "address" : "Trivandrum",

    "status" : "new",

    }]
```

So I want to get the name,address and status of schools from school collection where wrk_status in subscription collections is completed.
So at first I want to subscribe to subscription collection and get the school._id where wrk_status is completed and then subscribe to school collection to list the details of the schools with this school._id

Comment: You may come to regret naming a collection _subcriptions_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reywood:publish-composite package for that.

Provides a flexible way to publish a set of related documents from various collections using a reactive join. This makes it easy to publish a whole tree of documents at once. The published collections are reactive and will update when additions/changes/deletions are made.

Here is [link](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite)

Answer (score 0):

make a dictionary of schools

```
var sch_dict = {};
shools.forEach(function(sch) {
    sch_dict[sch._id] = sch
});

var result = []
subscriptions.forEach(function(sub) {
    if (sub.wrk_status = 'completed') {
       result.push(sch_id[sub.school._id]);
    }
})
```